# How to update SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have a question regarding updating a SQL Server CE database using Visual Studio & C#.

I have a database called `Database1` which has a table called `Cars`. The table `Cars` has 4 columns `CarID`, `Manufacturer`, `Model` and `Color`. `CarID` is the primary key and Identity is set to true.

I want to update a record in the database using the `CarID` column as I may want to update all the other columns - `Manufacturer`, `Model` and `Color`. In the attached project file, I have used the `CarID` Identity Number 1 but how do I do this without using the `CarID` Identity number? I understand that I need to declare the `CarID` somehow but cannot figure out how to do this.

Thanks!

[Download Project File](http://we.tl/WyNzLlVUBt)

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\update\update\Database1.sdf");
        conn.Open();

        SqlCeCommand update = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE [Cars] SET Manufacturer = @Manufacturer, Model = @Model, Color = @Color WHERE CarID = @CarID", conn);
        update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarID", 1);
        update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturer", txtManufacturer.Text);
        update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", txtModel.Text);
        update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", txtColor.Text);
        update.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Please post the relevant, minimal code sample directly here - don't make us go download stuff from somewhere else ....

Comment: You can use "SELECT @@IDENTITY" to get a recently added IDENTITY value - is that your issue??

Comment: ErikEJ - No that's not the issue. I am just looking to update a row in Cars table using the CarID column and am confused as to how to declare this CarID value instead of hardcoding it as in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare CarID, it will be automatically populated because you already set identity to this column.